# Scope from UISearchBar overlaps UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I'm trying to add an `UISearchController` on top of an `UITableView` (not in it's header) and I created a placeholder view for it in storyboard with a height constraint of 44.
In the normal state it all works fine but when I add some scope button, those overlap my first `UITableViewCell` and I'm unable to find a solution for this. I tried to re-set the height constraint of my placeholder view but I don't find the right functions to place it and couldn't find the "right" animation so it still looks nice.
My UISearchController looks like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    self.searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .Default
    self.searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    self.searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["Test1", "Test2"]
    self.searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()

    self.searchBarViewWrapper.addSubview(self.searchController.searchBar)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I found worked well. Add searchBar to `tableHeaderView` instead of your wrapper view:

```
searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["Test1", "Test2"]
tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
```

You can download the project to see in detail
http://www.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/CandySearch.zip

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I think with this solution the search bar would disappear when I scroll to the bottom but I want it to be visible all the time..

Comment: @Pascal_AC, have you figured out how to fix this problem? I have exactly the same issue. Works fine when not active, but once active, I have this overlap problem.